# Lucene search with Stop words in PhraseQuery doesn't return results

Tags: search, lucene, lucene.net

I have problem while searching with stop words!(that, at, the etc.)

I am using StandardAnalyzer to Index a text like "Surname At Birth".
When I Search (with StandardAnalyzer) using PhraseQuery with the phrase "Surname at birth" I do not receive any results.
This is the code where I create PhraseQuery:

```
                foreach(var word in search.Trim().Split(' '))
                {
                    phraseQuery.Add(new Term("content", word.ToLowerInvariant()));
                }
```

I am adjusting the slop when there are no results.

For example if I search for "Surname birth" I have results with "Surname at birth" inside.

It is like the StopWord "at" prevents the results

Answer (score 0):

Stopwords must also be removed at query time. If you don't do that then any query that requires that word to be present will not match any documents. Stopword removal is done at analysis time, analysis should also be performed on the query to get the terms that will be searched. (This is also needed for stemming, case-insensitivity.)

After analysys, a query like "Surname At Birth" (with quotes) will be converted to a PhraseQuery "Surname * Birth" (with a "hole" in the middle, using the "position increment" attribute on the first token).

I assume you are using Lucene.NET so check the docs at https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00009/api/queryparser/overview.html to use a query parser for your query.